# .htaccess rewriting trailing slashes encodes brackets to %5B

Tags: .htaccess

When `.htaccess` removes trailing slash from url containing square brackets `[` `]` it rewrites them to `%5B`. How to prevent that and what determines this behaviour?

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Always remove any trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not %5, that makes no sense. %5B and %5D are the square brackets [ and ]. is something else truncating it?

Comment: Adding the NE flag to the rewrite rule will stop escaping but as @Octopus said that isn't the escape for brackets.

Comment: @Octopus it is `%5B`, sorry my bad

Comment: as Omnikrys mentioned, try [R=301,L,NE] does that do the trick?